# User Variable Activity Scope in datastage

Tags: datastage

for example,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEbiJ.png)

if I set parameter (ex: index = 3) at UserVariable
and then, If i want to use this parameter in Job_Acitivity_312,
I have to set paramter also like this(in Job_Activity_312 job), right?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwhif.png)

I'm confusing about parameter's scope. like local varaible, globla varaible .etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a user variable is accessible anywhere downstream of the User Variables activity - there must be an unbroken set of links from the User Variable activity to where its value is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For example, If I set parameter Idx = 3 using User Variable Acitivity in SEQ_MAIN_JOB and SEQ_MAIN_JOB has a SEQ_INNER_JOB. In SEQ_INNER_JOB, can I use idx which I set parameter in SEQ_MAIN_JOB?

Answer (score 1):

Use the insert parameter button and navigate to the UserVariable entry to add the variable you created.

Details can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=activities-user-variables-activity-properties)

You can reference that variable like this: stage_label.parameter_name